# Where to set IPN URL for Pypal Recurring payments using new Paypal UI?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

I figured out that IPN URL for recurring payments should be set in Paypal Account settings.

I have found instruction for old Paypal UI
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-recurring-payments--net-30168

But I can't find where to set it in new UI, because it is completely different and it seems like it uses different terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences -> Account Settings -> My Sales -> Instant Payment Notifications

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify